# How to properly display pictures in a TableView from Firebase Storage in SWIFT

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have a chat app where people can talk in a group and a little picture is displayed in each cell to show who is talking. I managed to display these pictures from Firebase storage but **it is not always the right picture which is displayed at the right place.**

It only works when I go to the previous View Controller and coming back the chat View to see the pictures displayed properly in each cell.

I tried to use `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` probably not in the good way cause it did not work for me.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 
    let message = messageArray[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customMessageCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomMessageCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
// CHANGE TEXT ACCORDING TO SENDER
    if message.sender == Auth.auth().currentUser?.email{
        cell.messageBubble.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.30, green:0.68, blue:1.5, alpha:1.0)
        // ...
    } else {
        cell.messageBubble.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.94, green:0.94, blue:0.94, alpha:1.0)
        // ...
    }
   
    let theTimeStamp = messageArray[indexPath.row].createdAt
    let doubleTime = Double(theTimeStamp)
    let myDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: doubleTime )
    let dateToShow = myDate.calenderTimeSinceNow()
    
    cell.messageBodyTextView.text = messageArray[indexPath.row].messageBody
    cell.usernameLabel.text = messageArray[indexPath.row].name
    cell.timeLabel.text = dateToShow

     let imagePath = self.storageRef.reference(withPath:"\(message.uid)/resizes/profilImage_150x150.jpg")                   
               imagePath.getData(maxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
                                                               
        if let error = error {
            cell.userPicture.image = UIImage(named: "emptyProfilPic")
                                                                                                                  
        cell.userPicture.layer.cornerRadius = cell.userPicture.frame.height / 2
        cell.userPicture.clipsToBounds = true
                                                                   
        print("Got an error fetching data : \(error.localizedDescription)")                                                                       

       return
  }
                                                                
  if let data = data {
    cell.userPicture.image = UIImage(data: data)
    cell.userPicture.layer.cornerRadius = cell.userPicture.frame.height / 2
    cell.userPicture.clipsToBounds = true
                      }
    }
 
    return cell
}
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let you know, the problem was thaT I was reloading the table View after each message loaded. Instead, the best solution was to add a row to the tableview without reloaded the tableview after each message :

```
 self.ConvertationTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.messageArray.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to prepare the cell to be reusable with the proper override prepareForReuse().

For more clean code I suggest to you to implement the cells in separate cocoa Touch classes so it's easier to override and prepare for next data incoming, avoiding your problem.

What I mean it's a sort of this:

```
class mineCell:UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var text:UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var img:UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
       
    }
func updateCell(dataIn){
.
.
}
override func prepareForReuse() {
text.text = ""
img.image = nil
}
```

In your cellForRowAt table implementation just call the update function and pass your data like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let identifier = "mineCell"
        
        
        if let cell = mineTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as? mineCell {
            
           
            updateCell(dataIn)
            
            
            
            return cell
        }
        return mineCell()
    }
```

In this way you are always sure that your cell will be ready for every reuse and not loading wrong data from the cell above.

Comment: Thank you for your reply . I have done what you said but could you be more precise about the content of the function func updateCell(dataIn){} and dataIn ? I'm doing something wrong ( i'm new in swift )

Comment: So I used override prepareForReuse() to clean the cell before to reuse it but it did not work for me. Do you have more insight  ?

Comment: @olivierm usually the problem that you suffer is that you aren't preparing the cell with the override. As I understand from your code the cell isn't prepared on the reuse so, if something went wrong on download the right content you see the cached one. Mine code was to give a hint to you the proper way to use UITableViewCell along with the proper override in that class. Have you put a print("something") inside override to be sure that is fired properly?

Comment: Yes, I put a print() inside override and I confirm the it printed as expected, that's why I'm confuse